# gcloud app deploy fails on ruby-build for both 2.4.2 and 2.5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-app-engine

I am moving over (I think) from heroku to gcloud for deploying my rails applications.  I stepped through the full tutorial provided by google here [google appengine instructions](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/rails/appengine)

Running gcloud app deploy produces a lot of output.  However, it seems to show signs of trouble when it tries to download the ruby image from gcp-runtime/ruby/ubuntu16.

Each time at this spot,  I receive the following error:

1. "ruby-build: definition not found: ruby-2.5.1" - this is when I
   tried to deploy a 2.5.1 application.  and
2. "ruby-build: definition not found: ruby-2.4.2" - when I try to deploy a 2.4.2 application.

For this app deploy test, I only created the skeleton rails site using rails new command.  Executed bundle install and updated the app.yaml as instructed on the site using the secret key.

I am deploying in region north-america, if that info is useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you set up your Ruby development environment? You may profit from taking a look at the "Setting Up a Ruby Development Environment" documentation [page](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/docs/setup). 
The lot of output from the deployment command may prove highly significant, in context. What is the output from gcloud app deploy --verbosity=debug?

Comment: Sorry for late reply (i was pulled away from this task but am back at it now).  All my rails apps were created with the ruby that i access via rvm.   I see from the article you posted that I should use Rbenv instead so I switched everything over but I still get the same error when I try gcloud deploy either remotely or from google shell.  Switching to rbenv made my local testing a nightmare so I think I'm going to stick with heroku just for ease of use.  Or maybe Google Cloud Kubernetes instead of app engine.